# How to find all matching values in a full JSON document in Java

Tags: java, org.json

Right now I have a huge JSON document, and I would like to know how to find and add to a List all the keys with their values that match the key I look for, regardless of how deep they are in an JSON Array or Object.

[image: Example]

For example, for this JSON object, if I wanted the key "application", ideally it would return
`InternalUse`, `Selling` and `Fertilizer`

This is what I had before, but it obviously doesn't work as it's a JSON Array

```java
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayStr);
        return IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length())
                .mapToObj(index -> ((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(index)).optString(key))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using/looking for [tag:org.json] answers or was this just an arbitrary JSON related tag picked at random?

Comment: To be honest, just org.json, sorry for the trouble, I'll remove the tag

Comment: Does it have to be a pure Java solution or could you use something like, say, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

Comment: @RyanSchaefer I have tried feeding the raw JSON string into a JSONArray (which obviously didn't work) and just feed it into a IntStream in order to the key and value, collecting it into a List

Comment: @knittl the thing is I am already using org.json for most of the project, but I am open to look at jq to see if it works for my solution